# querySelectorAll elements not changing color of selected classes

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events, addeventlistener

I am trying to add an event listener to a HTML element on my site. The elements in question use a class name to group them together. However my event listener does not work when I try to click on the element that makes the changes. Here is the relevant code:

```js
// page elements for bright/dark mode

let brightOrDarkModeButton = document.querySelector('.sun-img-container')
let navBar = document.querySelector('.navBar')
let navBarParagraphElements = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-menu-option');

//

// DOM Events

brightOrDarkModeButton.addEventListener('click', changeBackgroundColour = () => {
  navBar.style.transition = 'background-color 0.15s linear';
  navBar.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  navBarParagraphElements.style.transition = 'color 0.15s linear';
  for (let i = 0; i < navBarParagraphElements.length; i++) {
    navBarParagraphElements[i].style.color = 'black';
  }
});
```

```html
<nav class="navBar">
  <a class='BP' href="REMOVED FOR PRIVACY">BP</a>
  <div class="nav-menu">
    <a href="#" class="nav-menu-option">Home</a>
    <a href="#about-me" class="nav-menu-option">About Me</a>
    <a href="#projects" class="nav-menu-option">Projects</a>
  </div>
  <a class="CV-container" href="REMOVED FOR PRIVACY">
    <p class="CV">CV</p>
  </a>
  <div class="sun-img-container">
    <img src="images/Sun.png">
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: `navBarParagraphElements` is a `NodeList`, which does not have a `style` property.

Comment: The error here is `navBarParagraphElements.style.transition = 'color 0.15s linear';`. Because this is a **collection**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

navBarParagraphElements is a list of elements. You have to set for each individually.

```js
// page elements for bright/dark mode

let brightOrDarkModeButton = document.querySelector('.sun-img-container')
let navBar = document.querySelector('.navBar')
let navBarParagraphElements = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-menu-option');

//

// DOM Events

brightOrDarkModeButton.addEventListener('click', changeBackgroundColour = () => {
    navBar.style.transition = 'background-color 0.15s linear';
    navBar.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    for (let i = 0; i < navBarParagraphElements.length; i++) {
        navBarParagraphElements[i].style.color = 'black';
        navBarParagraphElements[i].style.transition = 'color 0.15s linear'; //Add this here
    }
});
```

```html
<nav class="navBar">
  <a class="BP">BP</a>
  <div class="nav-menu">
    <a href="#" class="nav-menu-option">Home</a>
    <a href="#about-me" class="nav-menu-option">About Me</a>
    <a href="#projects" class="nav-menu-option">Projects</a>
  </div>
  <a class="CV-container">
    <p class="CV">CV</p>
  </a>
  <div class="sun-img-container">
    <img src="images/Sun.png" />
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: This worked exactly how I need it to. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

IMO you'd be better off using a single css class to toggle bright/dark

```js
// page elements for bright/dark mode

let brightOrDarkModeButton = document.querySelector('.sun-img-container')
let navBar = document.querySelector('.navBar')

//

// DOM Events

brightOrDarkModeButton.addEventListener('click', () => navBar.classList.toggle("dark"));
```

```css
.navBar.dark {
  transition: background-color 0.15s linear;
  background-color: white;
}

.navBar.dark .nav-menu-option {
  transition: color 0.15s linear;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navBar">
  <a class='BP' href="REMOVED FOR PRIVACY">BP</a>
  <div class="nav-menu">
    <a href="#" class="nav-menu-option">Home</a>
    <a href="#about-me" class="nav-menu-option">About Me</a>
    <a href="#projects" class="nav-menu-option">Projects</a>
  </div>
  <a class="CV-container" href="REMOVED FOR PRIVACY">
    <p class="CV">CV</p>
  </a>
  <div class="sun-img-container">
    <img src="images/Sun.png">
  </div>
</nav>
```